# Remove certain characters from all folder names in a folder

Tags: powershell, directory, windows-10, subdirectory, batch-rename

I have a folder with a load of subfolders with a random number at the beginning of their folder name. they are in this format:

```
1254170-folder1
1212340-folder2
3245417-folder3
```

What can I to rename all of them to

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

I tried something like this because I saw something similar about filenames.

```
for f in *\1*;do( mv "$f" "${f//1/ }");done
```

but it does not work. the powershell returned

```
At line:1 char:4
+ for f in *\1*;do( mv "$f" "${f//1/ }");done
+    ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
At line:1 char:17
+ for f in *\1*;do( mv "$f" "${f//1/ }");done
+                 ~
Missing statement body in do loop.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword
```

Not sure what should I do. I am using Windows 10 2004.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Get-ChildItem -path . -directory -recurse | Where {$_.Name -match '^\d+-'} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^\d+-',''}
```

- First command enumerates folders and all subfolders in current directory (`.`).
- Second command filters folders which starts with digits followed by dash (`^\d+-` regex)
- Third command renames the folders by removing `^\d+-` prefix

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Thank you, and sorry for replying 1.5 years later.

Answer (score 0):

I complet the @Renat code :

if you want exclude the directories with format without characters after the '-' (example 1254170-  )

And if you want your script continue same if a directory with the new name already exist

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\" -dir | where name -match "^\d+-.+$" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Split('-')[1]} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: `$_.Name.Split('-')[1]` will not work as intended if the foldername contained two or more dashes though..