# Remove extra square brackets from folder names

Tags: powershell, cmd, directory, rename, subdirectory

I have a series of folders, named as follow

```
[[1254170]][folder1]
[[1212340]][folder2]
[[3245417]][folder3]
```

I want to rename them all as

```
[1254170]folder1
[1212340]folder2
[3245417]folder3
```

or at least

```
[1254170][folder1]
[1212340][folder2]
[3245417][folder3]
```

I edited the batch command I learned from  [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259607/11604527) I asked a year ago.

```
Get-ChildItem -path . -directory -recurse | Where {$_.Name -match '^\[\[\d\]\]'} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^\[\[\d\]\]','^\[\d\]'}
```

The command went through but nothing happened.

I also tried an edited version of the command from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65262001/11604527)

```
Get-ChildItem * -Filter "*`[`[*`]`]*" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '\[\[','\[' -replace '\]\]','\]' }
```

and I got this error

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name.
At line:1 char:41
+ ... `[*`]`]*" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '\[\[','\[' -repl ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Someone help me please? I am using Windows 11. Thank you.

Comment: the replace - part of the `-replace` value does not need backslashs. It is literally. So `-replace '\[\[','['` is enough.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = "D:\test"

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "`[`[*`]`]`[*`]" -Directory|ForEach{
    Rename-Item -Literal $_.FullName $_.Name.Replace("[[","[").Replace("]]","]")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) with a [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operation to find the folder (directory) names of interest, capturing the substrings of interest via regex capture groups (`(...)`).
- You can pipe the matching folders to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) and use a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) to dynamically determine the new name, in which you can refer to the captured substrings via the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches).

  - Inside the delay-bind script block, you can use `-f`, the [string-formatting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), to synthesize the new name.

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse |
  Where-Object Name -match '^\[\[(.+?)\]\]\[(.+?)\]$' | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { '[{0}]{1}' -f $Matches[1], $matches[2] } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
$testinput = '[[1254170]][folder1]'
$testinput

## catch the string and replace using regex
### replacing the matched string with capture group 2

$testinput -replace '(\[)(.*?)(\])', '${2}'
$testinput


C:\> [1254170]folder1
```

### Regex Explanation

```
( open capture group 1
 \ escaping the next character
  [ matches [ literally
   ) closing capture group 1

    ( starting capture group 2
     . matching any character except line breaks
      * matches 0 or more of the preceding .
       ? making this lazy to capture as few as possible
        ) closing capture group 2
    
         ( starting capture group 3
          \ escaping the next character
           ] matches ] literally
            ) closing capture group 3

(\[)(.*?)(\])

( [ )( [1254170] )( ] )  ( [ )( folder1 )( ] )
( 1 )(    2      )( 3 )  ( 1 )(    2    )( 3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The latter [123123][folder1] i got with something like this:
`$str = '[[1254170]][folder1]'`
`$newstr = ($str | select-string '\[[\w-]+\]?').Matches.Value + ($str | select-string '\[[\w-]+\]+$').Matches.Value`
$newstr
[1254170][folder1]